# How to make Python reading a user input function?? (like f(x)=2x^2+3x+1)

Tags: python

I'm solving a problem in which i need to find the derivative of a function, but want the user to type-in the function, I can't use the 'input' command because the function is detected as 'string'

I tried using: 
y=float(input(print('Type the function:\n')
but i get:
ValueError: could not convert string to float

This is my code:

```
    import sympy as sp
    import numpy as np
    x=sp.Symbol('x')
    y=float(input(print('Type the function:\n')))
    yprime=y.diff(x)
    print(fprime)
```

As I said earlier, i need the derivative of the function but is detected as a string.

Comment: Give us some sample input please.

Comment: I tried 2*x**2, the derivative would be 4*x, I tried it as code and it worked, but it doesnt as input

Comment: `2*x**2` is of course no floating point number!

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I thought it would be turned into float somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from sympy import sympify, Symbol
import numpy as np
x = Symbol('x')
y=sympify(input('Type your function:'))
#y = x**2 + 1
yprime = y.diff(x)
print('the derivate of your function is :',yprime)
```

Comment: Hello, by using sympy can do sybolic calculations (including derivatives)

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval function to read a mathematical expression:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> eval('x + y')
3
>>>
```

Comment: eval has some security caveats

Comment: eval has some security caveats

Comment: Also wouldn't work with `2x^2+3x+1` as OP asked...would need to be `2*x**2+3*x+1`.

Comment: 2x^2+3x+1 is the example of a function, thats the way i may find it

Comment: @Vicant27 you can write a function that transform this kind of string into the format on intended input of eval

Comment: I tried eval, it worked for 2*x but it didn't for 2*x**2, i got:```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Mul") to str```

Comment: 2*x**2+3*x+1 this whole function works as a string in eval

Answer (score 0):

```
x=sp.Symbol('x')
y = input("Type the function:\n")
newY = ""
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] == "^":
        newY = newY + "**"
    else:
        newY = newY + y[i]
    if i<len(y)-1:
        if y[i].isdigit() and y[i + 1].isalpha():
            newY = newY+"*"
y = eval(newY)
print(y.diff(x))
```

Comment: eval is only good if the input comes from the same person why wrote / installed the code.

For any other use case eval has security issues.